# How to share props to a different route using react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-props

I am trying to share my props (`data, saveWorkButtonClicked, updateFBRDB`) from `<ProjectPage />` component route to `<Indent />` component route.

But getting the following error:

```js
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': async (data, setSpinner, updateFBRDB) => {
  setSpinner && setSpinner(true);
  let rawRoomData = String.raw`${J...<omitted>...
} could not be cloned.
```

**App.js**

```js
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/ProjectPage/:projectId" exact component={ProjectPage} />
    <Route path="/Indent/" render={(props) => <Indent {...props} />} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

**ProjectPage.js**

```js
history.push("/Indent/",
  {
    data: { ...project, rooms: project.rooms, ProjectId: project.ProjectId, ClientName: project.ClientName, Address: project.Address, AmountRecieved: project.AmountReceived, SiteEngineerId: project.SiteEngineersId },
    saveWorkButtonClicked,
    updateFBRDB,
  }
)

// saveWorkButtonClicked & updateFBRDB are API calls which will be called in <Indent />
```

**Indent.js**

```js
export default function Indent({ data, saveWorkButtonClicked, updateFBRDB }) {
    console.log('data in indent', data)
}
```

**NOTE:** Please give solutions where this can be implemented without Context/ Redux/ Mobx. Also, I am using react-router-dom v5.2.0

Comment: You cannot pass a function in the `state` of `history.push()`. Try removing those functions and see it's working. If so, you should pass those functions as `props` only.

Comment: @ShriHariL Removing those functions worked fine! But, now I need those functions as well. How do I do it? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an workaround. Have a state which keeps track of when you want to move to next page, so that we can use `Redirect` component conditionally with your desired data as props.

**App.js**

```jsx
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/ProjectPage/:projectId" exact component={ProjectPage} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

**ProjectPage.js**

```jsx
const [isDone, setIsDone] = useState(false);

const handleClick = () => {
    
    // Do all your works, when you want to `push` to next page, set the state.
    setIsDone(true);

}


if(isDone) {
   return (
     <>
       <Route path="/Indent"
              render={ props =>
                <Indent
                  {...props}
                  data={...}
                  saveWorkButtonClicked={saveWorkButtonClicked}
                  updateFBRDB={updateFBRDB}
                />
             }
       />
       <Redirect to="/Indent" />
     </>

   );
}
 

return (
  <div>Your Normal Profile Page goes here</div>
)
```

Comment: Now, I am getting `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'component' supplied to 'Route': the prop is not a valid React component`.

Comment: Oops. Try with `render`. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "share" props, you need to do one of two things. Either have the receiving component be a child of the propsharing component - in which case you can pass them as props directly. Else, you would need to pass them as state via a common ancestor component, which you would need to update by sending a callback down to the component that will update the state.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `state` to [`location`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/location) with this format

```
const location = {
   pathname: '/Indent/',
   state: {
     data: { ...project, rooms: project.rooms, ProjectId: project.ProjectId, ClientName: project.ClientName, Address: project.Address, AmountRecieved: project.AmountReceived, SiteEngineerId: project.SiteEngineersId },
     saveWorkButtonClicked,
     updateFBRDB,
   }
}
history.push(location)
```

And then using [`withRouter`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) to receive location values

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

function Indent({ location }) {
    const { state } = location
    const { data, saveWorkButtonClicked, updateFBRDB } = state || {}
 
    return <></>
}

export default withRouter(Indent)
```